# How do I check if an object collides with every object in an array?(Picture boxes)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collision

High school student here and I'm pretty rusty on my code. Okay, I have to have an image scroll along, and if it hits an object(in this case both are picture boxes), it resets.

The problem is when it gets to the If statement below, it won't work saying " 'bounds' is not a member of 'system.array' "

```
If PtbIcon.Bounds.IntersectsWith(objects.Bounds) Then
```

The error is the Objects.bounds

```
    If PtbIcon.Bounds.IntersectsWith(objects.Bounds) Then
        t = t + 1
        PtbIcon.Location = New Point(29, 236)
        'resets when you die, sets the score
    End If
    lblScore.Text = "Your Score Equals" & t

End
```

Why doesn't this work? Why? Is there a simpler way of checking all of this, such as calling a function which checks the bounds individually?

Comment: We have no idea how `objects` (really bad name) is declared, but whatever it is, it appears not to be a Type which has a bounds property.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq.

```
Dim t As Integer = 0

PtbIcon.All(Function(pb As PictureBox) As Boolean
    ' Checking goes here with pb
    ' Return True if you want to go through all of them
End Function)

lblScore.Text = "Your Score Equals" & t
```